# canonicalization XML in c++

Tags: c++, xml, digital-signature, canonicalization

I'm looking for the simplest way to canonicalize part of XML document in C++. Best option for me will be small library (I'm not c++ master) which I can simple add to my project.
If there is no such way and I have to create canonicalized part mysefl, what I have to remember about? To remove all unnecessary whitespaces, line breaks and to set attributes (and namespaces) alphabetically?
I have to create digital signature manually and this canonicalization is a part of this.

I'm working on Windows, so any tools from Linux won't help

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Apache xerces c++ library. the [SAX2Print](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/sax2print-2.html) sample is close to canonicalization ( expand end tags and namespaces ).

Comment: I saw this, but the problem is that xerces c++ is really heavy and it's too complicated for me to add it to my project...